# Excel how to return an array that meets a certain condition?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

If I have data in cell range `A1:A6` which is:

```
Apple
Banana
Cherry
Grape
Orange
Watermelon
```

Is there a way to return an array (in a single cell, for an intermediate step for a larger formula) which returns the above array except only those entries that satisfy a certain condition?

For example, if I wanted a formula to return an array of only those cells that contain the letter `n`, it would return this:

```
Banana
Orange
Watermelon
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Note I do *not* want to return an array of the same size, just with blank entries, i.e. I do not want:

```
""
Banana
""
""
Orange
Watermelon
```

Comment: Why the down votes? The question was how to return this result *in a single cell*, which is a complicated solution and is not posted anywhere else that I could find on SO.

Comment: Though I would ask it a little different, as a simple array form of TEXTJOIN will put the results in one cell.  What you want is to create an array that can then be used in other array type formulas that excludes all without an `n`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, should have clarified I was using Excel 2010 which does not have `TEXTJOIN`.

Comment: Your formula does not output the values into one cell.  You need something outside it to tell that one cell what to do with the array. You would need to higlight three cells and put the one array formula in to get the output, which Tom's answer replicates.  All I am saying, is you may want to specify better what you are planning on doing with the output, or as is, tom's answer is viable.

Comment: @ScottCraner The formula outputs exactly `{"Banana";"Orange";"Watermelon"}` into a single cell. The idea is to just have a proof of concept, for an intermediate step of a larger formula, rather than needing to use Tom's approach for helper cells. Why is it necessary to describe the application of the output? Is an abstract question like this not recommended?

Comment: You need to put that, you need to state in your question that it needs to reproduce an array that can be used in another formula.  It does not output the array into one cell.  Your formula puts this: https://imgur.com/a/mF8iY in one cell.  Your question is too abstract.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. Question edited to say it is for part of a larger formula. I will avoid questions too abstract in the future. (By the way, I understand that the result of the formula only displays the first result, but just that if you highlight the formula and press `F9` on keyboard it evaluates to the array.)

Comment: Yes I now that pressing F9 does that but again that is not what you asked.  remember, the normal visitor to this website does not know the history behind this question and will try to answer what they understand to be the actual question as you can see from the answers you got.  We cannot get in your head so you must be a specific as possible.  If I did not know the history behind this question I would have answered with TEXTJOIN as it would have put `Banana,Orange,Watermelon` in one cell, but could not be used in an array formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Here is the array formula (line break added for readability):

```
= INDEX(A1:A6,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("n",A1:A6)),
  (ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1)*{1,1})))))
```

Note, this is an array formula, meaning you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

There's some particularly odd things about this formula so I thought I would explain what is going below if you are interested. Some of what I explain below is probably obvious, but I am just being thorough.

To return a result from a list based on a *single* index, use this:

```
= INDEX(A1:A6,2)
```

This would return `Banana`.

To return results from a list based on *multiple* indices, you would think to use something like this:

```
= INDEX(A1:A6,{2;5;6})
```

This would ideally return `{Banana;Orange;Watermelon}`.

However, this does not return an array. Based on [a recent question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187863/can-excels-index-function-return-array), a very clever workaround to this problem was given:

```
= INDEX(A1:A6,N(IF({1},{2;5;6})))
```

This will return the desired result of `{Banana;Orange;Watermelon}`.

This I consider part 1 of the explanation.

---

Part 2 of the explanation is how the following returns `{2;5;6}`:

```
= MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("n",A1:A6)),(ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1)*{1,1}))
```

`MODE.MULT` is a function that returns the data in a set that appears most frequently. There are a few caveats, however:

1. Data must appear at least twice to be returned by `MODE.MULT`. If there is no duplicate data, it will return an error. For example, `MODE.MULT({1;2;3})` would return an error because there is no repeating data in the array `{1;2;3}`. Another example: `MODE.MULT({1;1;2}` would return `1` because `1` appears most often in the data.
2. If there is a "tie" in terms of what data appears the most, `MODE.MULT` returns an array of all tied entries. For example `MODE.MULT({1;1;2;2})` would return an array of `{1;2}`.
3. Most importantly, and probably the most peculiar but also most useful behavior of `MODE.MULT`, `MODE.MULT` *completely ignores* logical values (`TRUE` and `FALSE` values) when determining the mode of the data, *even if* they appear more often than the non-logical values in the data.

We can exploit these properties of `MODE.MULT` to get the desired array.

`ISNUMBER(SEARCH("n",A1:A6))` returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values where the data contains an `n`. Something like this:

```
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

`(ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1)` returns an array starting at `1` and increasing by 1 to however large the original array is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

`(ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1)*{1,1}` effectively just copies this column:

```
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
```

The `IF` statement is used to return the number in the array above if `TRUE`, and `FALSE` otherwise. (Since the `IF` statement contains no "else" clause, `FALSE` is the default value given.)

In this example, the `IF` statement would return this:

```
FALSE  FALSE
2      2
FALSE  FALSE
FALSE  FALSE
5      5
6      6
```

Taking `MODE.MULT` of the above formula will return `{2;5;6}` because as mentioned, `MODE.MULT` conveniently ignores the `FALSE` values in the array above when considering the mode.

It is necessary to consider the above array inside `MODE.MULT` instead of simply:

```
FALSE
2
FALSE
FALSE
5
6
```

Because as mentioned previously, `MODE.MULT` requires that *at least* two entries in the data are required to match for it to return a value.

Comment: @Tom - It looks like this is a prepped question, or something OP is trying to answer for the community? (Asked and answered around same minute, so I assume this is a contrived question/answer?)

Comment: @Tom, yes, it is asking and answering own question. This was based on recent findings and I thought the solution was rather obscure, so I wanted to post it for the community.

Comment: @Tom also not sure why the solution isn't working for you, just pasted my formula verbatim into my worksheet and it returned expected results when entered as array formula.

Comment: @Tom there is nothing wrong with this approach.  And it is something to which we can direct others as they have the same question.  This exact question has been asked twice in the past few days. It is a great base on which we can use other formula.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the {1,1} array - this shorter version works for me - `=INDEX(A1:A6,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("n",A1:A6)),(ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1)*{1,1})))))`

Comment: Thanks @barryhoudini. I had just assumed that the arrays in the `IF` statement had to be the *exact* same size. I believe this is the 2nd time within a week that you pointed out to me that making arrays the exact same size is not necessary in some situations... fail haha. Thanks again, I will edit answer.

Comment: No problem - I know that `XOR LX` developed and/or expanded some of these techniques - lots of good stuff on his website https://excelxor.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$7)=0)*(FIND("n",$A$2:$A$7)>0),0))
```

This is an array formula so will need to entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Input and output**

[image: Input and Output]

- The `INDEX` returns an element from a range
- The `MATCH` allows us to find the position of the row(s) to return
- The `COUNTIF` is to make sure we only select unique values in the results
- The `FIND` returns only rows where there is a `n` present in the string

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, the question was how to return this array *in a single cell* (as an intermediate step to another larger formula).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function ContainsN(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    ContainsN = ""
    For Each r In rng
        If InStr(1, UCase(r.Value), "N") > 0 Then ContainsN = ContainsN & Chr(10) & r.Value
    Next r
    ContainsN = Mid(ContainsN, 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post while searching for a solution to a similar problem: return an array of expiration dates for all batches of a specific SKU.

I transposed a filter function so that my array of `Batch Exp` dates would appear on the same line as my Inventory SKU.

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Batch EXP'!$A$2:$A$1000,('BatchEXP'!$B$2:$B$1000=Inventory!$R4))),"No Expiration")
```

Added a concatenate column onto my filter range where I could combine quantities (F4) associated with each expiration date (I4).

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(I4,"MM-DD-YY")," x ",TEXT(F4,"#,#"), " units")
```

It works great and returns all an array for SKUS that match the criteria I setout. Could even take one step further to only return batches > X %, qty, etc. Here is example of output for a SKU:

`11-15-22 x 40 units    11-01-22 x 5,216 units`