# Return an array based on Criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, match

first time posting and looking for some help (please be nice :D)!

I am looking for an array formula to return an array, if the values in a range contain certain text.

For example, in the table below, I have a Lookup range in the left column. I wish to return the values containing "Country", and the end result would be an array with the relevant values, as per the right column. Furthermore, I only want to return the values containing "Country", and not have any blank spaces within the resulting array.

I found this thread: [Excel how to return an array that meets a certain condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398637/excel-how-to-return-an-array-that-meets-a-certain-condition) and tried replicating it in G-sheets, but couldn't produce the result I was looking for. This might be because the formulas in Excel and G-sheets may be written/interpreted differently, and I'm no expert on that.

Finally, I am keen to work out the solution in Google Sheets, as I wish to work collaboratively with my team as the sole (barely much of a) "tech guy" in the team.

Any help will be appreciated!

| Lookup Range | End Result |
| --- | --- |
| CountrySouth Korea | CountrySouth Korea |
| CountryJapan | CountryJapan |
| CausesHealth |  |
| CausesAgriculture |  |
| SupportResume |  |
| SupportInterviews |  |
| SupportCoaching |  |

[Image of the Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ3nQ.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A:A; REGEXMATCH(A:A; "Country"))
```

keep in mind that regex is case-sensitive

[image]

Comment: This is great, is there a non-case sensitive solution as well?

Comment: @ZhihaoChia sure: `=FILTER(A:A; REGEXMATCH(A:A; "(?i)Country"))`