# Reference to last worksheet in Excel Function to Sum same range across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, worksheet-function, worksheet

I've tried a few formula options but nothing is quite working the way I would like it to.

I'm using a very simple SUM formula to total across all the worksheets in my workbook. Currently it's set up like this:

`=SUM('1:10'!D3)`

However, I'm likely going to add more worksheets and I want them included in this total. I've tried a few different versions of "wshNameLast" or "getlastwsname" that I've found in different articles here but they are all giving me a #REF error. Is there a formula I'm able to put in here without turning to VBA?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the following link https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/ you should be able to adapt to your needs

Comment: Have a hidden blank worksheet at the end and just reference that?

Comment: Starting with the named range in Michal's [suggestion](https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/) I found that `=COUNTA(sheetNames)` gives the number of worksheets the named range (or, if they are all named sequentially, the name of the last sheet), then tried `INDIRECT` to try to reproduce your formula. I'm giving up for now but I think it's possible, perhaps using `SUMPRODUCT` like explained [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/668942-using-indirect-function-to-sum-across-multiple-sheets.html).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

@BigBen's comment to the question >>> "Have a hidden blank worksheet at the end and just reference that" >>> is really practical and the easiest solution.

But just to make it dynamic

Referred to .. [Jeffrey Weir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189998/9808063)
and
[Return array with Index Function](https://exceljet.net/formula/return-array-with-index-function)

and as suggested by @Michal Rosa in comment on this question
[How to generate list of Sheet Names](https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/)

and as suggested by @ashleedawg in comment on this question
[using indirect function to sum across multiple sheets](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/668942-using-indirect-function-to-sum-across-multiple-sheets.html)

Created workbook with 5 worksheets.

First Sheet is `Sheet5` and so on the last is `Sheet1`.

Each Sheet except the first has value in `B5`.

First defined the name for `SheetNames` array `=GET.WORKBOOK(1)`

[image]

Then it was easy to sum Values in `B5` of all the the Sheets(Including the first) with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&SheetNames&"'!B5")))`

But what if one has to enter a formula in the First Sheet(`Sheet5`) in `B5` to sum all remaining Sheets' `B5`. The formula above returns circulating error.

The formula below can be entered in the first Sheet `B5` to Sum all the sheets from Second to last. Note that, its an `array formula`. (Copy without curly bracket and enter with `ctrl+shift+enter`)

`{=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetNames,N(IF((1),ROW(INDIRECT(2&":"&SHEETS())))))&"'!B5")))}`

`INDIRECT(2&":"&SHEETS())` starts the array with Second Sheet and Ends with last sheet (number calculated with Sheets() function)

So, if one wants to start array/ sum from Sheet number 3 use `INDIRECT(3&":"&SHEETS())` with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

One can replace `ROW function` with an `array of Sheet Numbers`. For example, to sum only Second and Fifth Sheets

`{=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetNames,N(IF((1),{2,5})))&"'!B5")))}`

Also, `&"'!B5"` can be replaced with `&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` to sum current formula cell address across multiple sheets.

Comment: SheetNames = MID(GET.WORKBOOK(1),FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1),1)+1,LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1)))