# Is it possible to create an excel 3D formula with dynamic sheet bookmarks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an 3d excel formula with a dynamic reference to the bookmark sheets (start and end of range). The end goal is to have a standardised calculation sheet that can be used to consolidate different groupings (each of which will most likely have numerous sheets) based upon a provided sheet specific input.

I have contemplated the use of a `CHOOSE` function but this feels less dynamic and bulkier. I have also contemplated using an `INDIRECT` function (and just generating specific sheet names instead of bookmarks) but would rather avoid the volatility and need for identifying individual sheets if possible.

I have attached a simplified screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example setup]

The formula that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
=SUM("'"&$E$4&">:<"&$E$4&"'!A1")
```

When I `F9` (using the variables from the screenshot) this I get the following:

```
=SUM("'A>:<A'!A1")
```

Whereas the statically typed formula that I am trying to replicate is this:

```
=SUM('A>:<A'!A1)
```

Comment: You can dynamically refer to worksheets with named range .. [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545265/9808063) .. and .. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893874/9808063)

Comment: Hi Naresh, cheers for the GET.WORKBOOK suggestion. This is something that I was actually playing around with earlier as well and have since incorporated into my solution (based upon JMPs response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bookmarks are already sequential, and the sheets inside them have a consistent naming schema, then you can find the location of the bookmarks with

```
=SHEET("a>")
```

and

```
=SHEET("<a")
```

Then you can use `INDIRECT` and `SEQUENCE` to run through each sheet inbetween.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet"&(A3+SEQUENCE(A4-A3-1))&"!A1"))
```

In the example, `A3` and `A4` hold the sheet number of the bookmarks, and the sheets are eponymous, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4`, etc..., and we sum the `A1` cell in each sheet.

[image: bookmarks]

Comment: Unfortunately the sheets inside don't necessarily have a consistent naming schema but I have been able to tweak the example that you provided to produce the desired outcome. For reference this is the approach that I have taken:

=SUM(INDIRECT(INDEX(sheets,A3+SEQUENCE(A4-A3-1))&"!A1")).

Where "sheets" is a named range with the following formula:


=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")&T(NOW())#.


Thank you very much for your contribution, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `SUM` across multiple worksheets: the entirety of each range has to be within a single worksheet.  `SUM('A>:<A'!A1)` is an invalid formula — you would need to use `SUM('A>'!A1,'1'!A1,'2'!A1,'<A'!A1)` to get the result you want. (i.e. specifying multiple ranges)

`INDIRECT` and `CHOOSE` will ignore things like Sheet Order, so can't be used for this either.

You *might* be able to work something out with VBA, using `Worksheet.Index` references, but not with normal Excel formulae.  Here is a User Defined Function (put it in a new Module in VBA, not in the Worksheet!) that should do what you are after:

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Function SUM3D(reference1 As Range, reference2 As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    
    SUM3D = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'Default to an Error
    On Error GoTo FunctionError
    
    Dim SumRange As String, TotalSum As Double, TempSum As Variant, StartIndex As Long, EndIndex As Long, CurrIndex As Long
    TotalSum = 0
    TempSum = 0
    
    'Create the 2D range bounded by the 2 references, which will extend through the sheets
    SumRange = Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Range(reference1.Address(True, True, xlA1, False)), _
        Worksheets(1).Range(reference2.Address(True, True, xlA1, False)) _
        ).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)
    
    StartIndex = reference1.Worksheet.Index
    EndIndex = reference2.Worksheet.Index
    
    
    If StartIndex = EndIndex Then
        'Same sheet, no need to make it 3D
        SUM3D = Application.Sum(reference1, reference2)
    Else
        'Different sheets, so cycle through them.
        For CurrIndex = StartIndex To EndIndex Step Sgn(EndIndex - StartIndex)
            'Ignore Charts, DialogSheets, MacroSheets, etc
            If Sheets(CurrIndex).Type = xlWorksheet Then
                TempSum = Application.Sum(Sheets(CurrIndex).Range(SumRange))
                
                If IsError(TempSum) Then
                    SUM3D = TempSum 'Return the Error
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    TotalSum = TotalSum + TempSum 'Add this sheet's sum to the total
                    TempSum = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next CurrIndex
    End If
    
    SUM3D = TotalSum
FunctionError:
    On Error GoTo -1 'Clear error handler
End Function
```

Comment: With normal excel we can refer to worksheets with index dynamically with named range .. [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545265/9808063) .. and .. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893874/9808063) .. but with the risk of rearranging the sheets order :) I guess

Comment: @Naresh Hmm…  I wonder if an ArrayFormula/`SUMPRODUCT` could be set up to work on "every sheet between these two indices" then?

Comment: Apologies, I may not be getting you correctly. If the cell is the same on each sheet like in this case, A1, I think it could be done with that kind of named range. If the cells are different on different sheets, then no.

Comment: Hi Chronocidal, I have actually managed to resolve my issue with a modified version of JMPs suggestion but thanks for your input as well, it's much appreciated. However, I can confirm that "SUM('A>:<A'!A1)" is a valid (and working) formula. It makes use of something called a "3D reference" which I'd highly recommend reading up on if you haven't come across them before as they can be very useful.