# How to convert an "enumerate" to array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to calculate sum(a.*b) = a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2]+.....

The array a with length n is present in the sheet. Values of b though are not present directly.
To get b, there is a column of data and n indexes. b[i] = data[indexs[i]]

One way to find sum(a.*b) is to first buffer the value of b using INDEX(data, indexes) and then SUM(a * b).
I want it to be done in one cell with no buffering. So I tried replacing b with the formula of b like SUM(a * INDEX(data, indexes)). But excel considers INDEX(data, indexes) to be iterable and gives me [SUM(a * b[1]), SUM(a * b[2]), ...]

How do I tell excel to take INDEX(data, indexes) as an array?

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBKCG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier versions of Excel (pre-O365), you have to use the following manoeuvre to deliver an array using Index [as described here](https://exceljet.net/formula/return-array-with-index-function):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D4*INDEX(A2:A10,N(IF({1},B2:B3))))
```

The curly brackets around the 1 {1} are not strictly necessary, but I tend to leave them in to signal that I am using this trick.

[image]

Comment: Tom, question.. is this only tied to versions prior to O365? I just used `=SUM(D3:D4*INDEX(A2:A10,B2:B3))` and it worked. I guess it's really just the O365 array working kicking in. I don't have older versions to try. Btw, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47187863/9758194) is an interesting read indead. Neat trick =)

Comment: To the best of my belief you have to do this in all versions prior to O365 - I am using Excel 2019. Interesting reading the references - the original article by EXCELXOR was way back in 2014 but I have no idea how they discovered the trick in the first place.

Comment: @TomSharpe The earliest description of that technique I've seen was by the late Laurent Longre (who wrote the old Morefunc Add-in for Excel)  back in the mid `00`'s.